# Converting date string to with unknown format to date C#

Tags: string, parsing, date

In my c# application, in one of the input fields user can enter date in any format like "MM/dd/yyyy" or "dd/MM/YY" or "YYYY/MM/dd" I want to convert the input to  say "MM/dd/YYYY". How can i do this with date parsing.

Comment: try this `DateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yy")` !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
DateTime dateValue;

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
{
    return null;
}
```

after this, check dateValue variable value.